# GridView not firing SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, extension-methods

Hi I've written this extension method on a GridView. Once the selected index is changed I want SelectedIndexChanged event to fire. But, it's not happening. Any particular reason?
How can I get this fixed?

```
<Extension()>
       Public Sub SelectRowByCallId(ByVal gridviewObj As GridView, ByVal callId As String)
        Dim selectedIndex As Int32 = 0
        Dim pageIndex As Int32 = 0
        Dim gridViewPages As Int32 = gridviewObj.PageCount

        For index = 0 To gridViewPages
            gridviewObj.PageIndex = index
            gridviewObj.DataBind()

            For i = 0 To gridviewObj.DataKeys.Count - 1
                If (Convert.ToString(gridviewObj.DataKeys(i).Value) = callId) Then
                    selectedIndex = i
                    pageIndex = index
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next i

        Next index

        gridviewObj.PageIndex = pageIndex
        gridviewObj.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
        gridviewObj.DataBind()


    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have declare this also on asp control, on the aspx side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `SelectedIndex` property won't fire events, but calling `SelectRow` method will.

Answer (score 0):

If Aristos is right then
SET AutoPostBack to True

Comment: GridView doesn't have that property